# Add a react component for each querySelectorAll() that is found?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need a way to add my react component to the screen, for each place they find the id "#card".

```
const container = document.querySelectorAll('#card');

ReaactDOM.render(<App />, container);
```

The code above doesn't render anything on the page.  With the error: Uncoaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.  I've researched and found that querySelectorAll only returns a NodeList that I need to loop. However, all attempts I've tried aren't working.

Not sure if quuerySelectorAll is the right choice. Or if I need to fix how I'm calling it.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div class="card_container">
        {console.log(cards)}
        {cards.map() => {
                <div>{cardNumber}</div>
        }

    </div>
  );
};

for (const el of document.querySelectorAll(".react-container")) {
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, el);
}
```

```
[Stack 1]
[Stack 2]
[Stack 2]
[Stack 3]
[Stack 3]
[Stack 3]
```

Comment: Have you tried:

const container = document.getElementById('card');
ReaactDOM.render(<App />, container);

Comment: @TheKNVB Same error. Should note, that I have multiple #card id's on the page, and not just one. So ideally, It needs to style each id

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns an array that you need to iterate.  You also should not have duplicate `id`s anywhere in a page.  Show how you are trying to iterate.  Saying "all attempts I've tried aren't working" and not showing them lacks debugging details.

Comment: We're really close to an [mre].  Please also provide data for `cards` that will help reproduce the issue that you mentioned.

Comment: @zero298 Adding as much as I could. In the database, 3 card containers. however,r when I console.log it, it's printing like shown above. Card stacks are [K,K], [Q,Q], and [Q,A]. all have class name .react-container. Does this help? or do I need to add more info? Not sure why it's printing that that order though {stack 1 one time, stack 2 two times, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually iterate the array that `querySelectorAll` returns.  You should also ***never*** duplicate `id` within a page.

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>I'm a React app!</div>
  );
};

for (const el of document.querySelectorAll(".react-container")) {
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, el);
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div class="react-container"></div>
<div class="react-container"></div>
<div class="react-container"></div>
<div class="react-container"></div>
```

Comment: This works. But if each row has different amount of cards (row 1: 1 row 2: 2 row 3: 3) but this is displaying only 3 cards on each row. Is the error in the loop here? or my app code? (i.e. its running the last row three times)

Comment: @journalsup I am not sure.  Please update your question with the code that you are trying.

Comment: added. Right now I have a code in my App() that returns cards.map. It's supposed to go through each card and spit back just the name. It's doing it correctly, (Q, A) in database, But Q,A shows up threee times. Rather than, K,K, Q,Q. which is what I put in in the first two containers.